# Default Select Option Using JSON Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following code that populates a certain select item on a page:

```
<select ng-model="activity.selectedParent" ng-options="parent as parent.title for parent in parents track by parent._id"></select><br>
```

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to specify a default option such that I can give it a Title and an ID. For instance, if default is selected, then `activity.selectedParent.Title = "None"` and `activity.selectedParent.id = 0`. Is this possible to somehow specify this within the `<select>` tag using Angular directives? Otherwise, what is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: See [`ng-selected`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question you want to set an object even if the default is selected, then you can do it in two ways:

1. Using [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive inside your `select` tag, as follows:

   `ng-init="selectedParent = { '_id': 0, 'title': 'None' };"`
2. Initializing your object in your controller:

   `$scope.selectedParent = { "_id": 0, "title": "None" };`

**EDIT:**

I think I got what you want, now: you want to have a default option instead of a blank as first option, right? If so, you can simply add this element to your existent array, using [***unshift***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp) method, so it'll be placed as first element as below:

```
$scope.parents.unshift($scope.selectedParent);
```

Here's a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parents = [  
     {  
        "_id":1,
        "title":"first"
     },
     {  
        "_id":2,
        "title":"second"
     },
     {  
        "_id":3,
        "title":"third"
     },
     {  
        "_id":4,
        "title":"four"
     }
  ];

  $scope.selectedParent = {
    "_id": 0,
    "title": "None"
  };

  $scope.parents.unshift($scope.selectedParent);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedParent" ng-options="parent as parent.title for parent in parents track by parent._id"></select>
  <hr> 
  Selected: <span ng-bind="selectedParent | json"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I Use `ng-init`, will the default value still remain an option even if  select something else and then decide to come back to default again?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, can you see my edit? I think I understood you want now.. let me know if I'm missing something..

Comment: Did you add Unshift? What does that do? Basically, I am always displaying a list of parents that I query from DB. However, I also want to have an option on that list that makes the entry have no parent (i.e. become child-eligible itself). Hence, I was wondering how to add that to the list.

Comment: Unshift adds an elements to the first position, which is you want. Can you edit your question to demonstrate it?

Comment: Having read your edit, I think it is almost what I want. If an entry has a parent, I would like the parent item to be selected from the list. If it has no parent (it is child-eligible itself), then the "No Parent" entry that we added should be displayed. Either way, the "No Parent" entry should always be present in the list to provide a way to edit this item from a being a child to being a self-sufficient specie. Hopefully, I am being clear.

Comment: I have tried your way. It works. :) The only thing remaining is to display the proper entry for parent upon the load of the page. Say, if activity.parent contains the actual `_id` for the entrie's parent, is there a way I could compare against it and set the list to default to the title of that `_id`?

Comment: Glad to help:) Hmm.. do you have nested ng-repeats?

Comment: No nested ng-repeats on this page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116820/discussion-between-developer033-and-madphysicist).

Answer (score 1):

If the array used in the ng-options doesn't contain the value you wish to set as default, then the easiest way to achieve this is to add the default value to the array.

First set the selectedParent in the controller

```
$scope.selectedParent = { "_id": 0, "title": "None" };
```

Then add it to the first position in the array

```
$scope.parents.splice(0,0,$scope.selectedParent);
```

And finaly set the ng-model of the select to `ng-model="$scope.selectedParent"`